# Mysql in Docker, Your password has expired

Tags: mysql, docker

I was using docker-machine and older version of MacOS but now I updated to Monterey and docker-machine is depreciated so I have to use docker desktop for mac.

I have docker-compose file and I have mysql container and whenever I close my mysql (5.7.9) container and reopen it or recreate it, it always throws this error:

```
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [1862] Your password has expired. To log in you must change it using a client that supports expired passwords. (SQL: SHOW FULL TABLES WHERE table_type = 'BASE TABLE')
```

Whenever I close my container I have to run below code in the mysql container by logging in with my root user

```
SET GLOBAL default_password_lifetime = 0;
```

Is there a way to make it persistent so I do not have to enter this command whenever I open the container?

I tried changing my user's password but not worked.

I do not have config file for mysql.

Answer (score 1):

Use `SET PERSIST` instead of `SET GLOBAL` to make it persistent by writing it to internal .cnf-File:
[Doc for SET](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/set-variable.html)

Or add it to your custom .cnf-File in `/etc/mysql/conf.d/`

```
[mysqld]
default_password_lifetime=0
```

To make it work you have to login and change your password once due to mysql running in sandbox-mode then.. `SET PASSWORD = 'pwd';` or `SET PASSWORD FOR <user> = 'pwd';`

Or use `ALTER USER <user> PASSWORD EXPIRE NEVER` on given user instead of setting it globally.

Comment: ALTER USER ..... PASSWORD EXPIRE NEVER this did not work.

Comment: You have to quit sandbox mode before by `SET PASSWORD` or `ALTER USER IDENTIFIED BY 'pwd' REPLACE 'old_pwd'` . Since mysql 8.0.27 `SET` is not supported anymore in sandbox.

Comment: Sorry my bad, I'm using Mysql 5.7.9 I've forget to tell.

Answer (score 0):

You can try in docker-compose.yml Add the parameter `command: --default_password_lifetime = 0`

Comment: It threw an error "Connection refused", I guess I put this command to somewhere else to run everytime.

Comment: You need to modify the MySQL database password first, and then add the command configuration